# Drake C++ tutorials

Tags: drake

can you recommend me C++ tutorials (or point me to the right direction how to learn Drake using C++), especially focused on robotic manipulators? Also what visualizer do you use within C++, since MeshCat seems to be used only for Python or Julia.

Thank you in advance

Comment: We have MeshcatVisualizer in C++ as well, see https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1geometry_1_1_meshcat_visualizer.html

Comment: We have a selection of "examples" in C++. See https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/tree/master/examples. The subfolder "multibody" might be useful for you. We also have a "meldis" tool that makes visualizing with MeshCat easier. See for example: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/examples/allegro_hand/joint_control/README.md.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find tutorials, books or other off-site resources are off-topic according to the [help/on-topic] guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Even though [Drake's tutorials](https://drake.mit.edu/#tutorials) are written in Python, all of the same ideas apply to Drake's C++ library.  Drake's Python library is just a thin wrapper over the C++ API, so all of the concepts, class, and function names are all the same.  Our hope is that the Python tutorials are a good starting point, even for users who plan to use Drake from C++.

To see various C++ sample code, you can also browse the examples:
https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/tree/master/examples

The `drake/examples/manipulation_station` example involves an arm, gripper, and objects to manipulate.

Drake C++ does support MeshCat just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a third party Drake C++ tutorial https://drake.guzhaoyuan.com/
However, it is not maintained now and some of its contents may be out-of-date. In this tutorial, the author describes how to write `Build.bazel` and use the `bazel` build system, which I think is the major gap between the official python tutorial and using drake in C++. There seems to be no official helper document for how to use the `bazel` function like `drake_cc_library` or `drake_cc_binary`.

If you would like to use Drake C++ as an external dependency, here are some nice official examples https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake-external-examples